# vulnerable to Intent Redirection issue in android App

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-security

I am facing an Intent Redirection issue. My application has been rejecting by google. I added **exported=false** in the manifest. I am stuck on this issue for the last 1 month. I do not find an issue in the google play console. please help me to fix this issue.[image]

Comment: You fixed it problem?

Comment: yes ,it  was fixed @Андрей

Comment: @GayatriDarji how could you fix the problem?

Comment: @BehnoudSherafati I am using cashfree payment gateway .  updated lib version create this issue . I am downgrade  lib version .

Comment: @GayatriDarji can i have that exact library version? am also facing same issue. now am using - implementation files('libs/cashfreesdk-1.4.9.8-release.aar')

Comment: @BehnoudSherafati Which library version you used to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nothing worked Vishal